# following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'wp_enqueue_script' (T_STRING) in wp-garden/functions.php on line 277

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adds JavaScript Bootstrap.

```
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.2');
```

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
wp_register_script ('bootstrap', 'get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
```